# JavaScript Array short circuiting the script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a huge Array in javascript...It's 4 levels deep and many elements long.  I create it at runtime w/ php so that everything on the page runs smoothly and no queries need to be done.

However, right now, I have some sort of problem with the Array and my html file isn't seeing the javascript functions that are listed after the Array.  With testing I've made the array shorter and gotten it to work, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's cutting off the rest of the script in it's full form.

I would appreciate any answers that either tell me 
A. How to use Firebug to find the problem (I'm very new to Firebug)
or 
B. Tell me what the #$%^ the problem is!

I'll list my entire script below (the output from the php).  The Array that's having trouble is "inventoryNames".  I've checked to see if the problem is the amount of parantheses but I'm 99% positive it is now.  If I comment it out everything works fine. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var inventoryNames = 
        Array(
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("AC/DC", "Back in Black", "36", "VG++", "12", ""), 
                    Array("AC/DC", "Back in Black", "37", "VG", "8", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "30", "VG++", "10", ""), 
                    Array("AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "38", "VG", "5", ""), 
                    Array("AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "35", "NM", "16", ""), 
                    Array("AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "39", "NM", "14", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Al Green", "Call Me", "40", "G", "5", ""), 
                    Array("Al Green", "Call Me", "31", "NM", "15", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Al Green", "Let's Stay Together", "32", "NM", "12", ""), 
                    Array("Al Green", "Let's Stay Together", "33", "VG++", "10", ""), 
                    Array("Al Green", "Let's Stay Together", "34", "VG", "8", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("B.B. King", "Confessin' the Blues", "45", "VG++", "9", ""), 
                    Array("B.B. King", "Confessin' the Blues", "42", "NM", "35", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("B.B. King", "Lucille", "43", "VG++", "14", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("B.B. King", "Singin' the Blues", "41", "NM", "16", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("B.B. King", "Sings Spirituals", "44", "VG++", "10", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Bad Company", "Bad Company", "12", "G", "2", ""), 
                    Array("Bad Company", "Bad Company", "13", "M", "38", "1st Edition"), 
                    Array("Bad Company", "Bad Company", "14", "VG+", "8", ""), 
                    Array("Bad Company", "Bad Company", "3", "VG++", "13", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Bob Dylan", "Another Side of Bob Dylan", "48", "VG++", "20", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Bob Dylan", "Blonde on Blonde", "50", "M", "35", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Bob Dylan", "Highway 61 Revisited", "49", "NM", "25", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Bob Dylan", "The Freewheelin' Bob Dylan", "46", "VG++", "13", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Bob Dylan", "The Times They Are A-Changin'", "47", "NM", "25", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Boston", "Boston", "52", "VG++", "12", ""), 
                    Array("Boston", "Boston", "53", "VG++", "10", ""), 
                    Array("Boston", "Boston", "51", "VG", "7", ""), 
                    Array("Boston", "Boston", "23", "VG", "6", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Charlie Parker", "Jazz at Massey Hall", "54", "NM", "42", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Green River", "56", "VG++", "13", ""), 
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Green River", "57", "NM", "16", ""), 
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Green River", "55", "VG+", "10", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Willy and the Poor Boys", "60", "NM", "15", ""), 
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Willy and the Poor Boys", "114", "NM", "16", ""), 
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Willy and the Poor Boys", "58", "G", "5", ""), 
                    Array("Creedence Clearwater Revival", "Willy and the Poor Boys", "59", "VG", "7", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Dave Brubeck", "Time Out", "61", "NM", "18", ""), 
                    Array("Dave Brubeck", "Time Out", "62", "VG+", "10", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("David Allan Coe", "Longhaired Redneck", "63", "VG+", "8", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("David Allan Coe", "Rides Again", "64", "VG+", "6", ""), 
                    Array("David Allan Coe", "Rides Again", "65", "NM", "10", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("David Bowie", "Hunky Dory", "18", "NM", "40", "Rare!")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("David Bowie", "Ziggy Stardust and the Spiders From Mars", "21", "VG++", "15", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Earth, Wind & Fire", "Earth, Wind & Fire", "67", "VG+", "10", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Earth, Wind & Fire", "That's the Way of the World", "66", "NM", "15", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Foghat", "Energized", "68", "NM", "10", ""), 
                    Array("Foghat", "Energized", "2", "M", "2", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("George Harrison", "All Things Must Pass", "69", "NM", "35", ""), 
                    Array("George Harrison", "All Things Must Pass", "1", "M", "2", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Guns N Roses", "Appetite for Destruction", "70", "NM", "20", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Hank Williams", "Hank Williams Sings", "29", "M", "55", ""), 
                    Array("Hank Williams", "Hank Williams Sings", "71", "NM", "70", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Herbie Hancock", "Empyrean Isles", "72", "VG++", "10", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Herbie Hancock", "Head Hunters", "74", "VG++", "13", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Herbie Hancock", "Maiden Voyahe", "73", "VG++", "13", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Huey Lewis & the News", "Sports", "76", "VG+", "3", ""), 
                    Array("Huey Lewis & the News", "Sports", "77", "VG", "2", ""), 
                    Array("Huey Lewis & the News", "Sports", "75", "NM", "8", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Its a Beautiful Day", "Its a Beautiful Day", "20", "VG++", "10", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("James Brown", "Prisoner of Love", "78", "VG++", "18", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Jimi Hendrix", "Are You Experienced", "22", "VG+", "12", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("John Lee Hooker", "John Lee Hooker Plays and Sings the Blues", "81", "VG++", "15", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("John Lee Hooker", "Travelin'", "80", "VG++", "15", ""), 
                    Array("John Lee Hooker", "Travelin'", "82", "VG+", "15", ""), 
                    Array("John Lee Hooker", "Travelin'", "79", "VG++", "20", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Mazaak", "Fat Man Suicide", "25", "M", "200", "Includes classics like "Cream Green and Beans" and the title track "Fat Man Suicide"!")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Miles Davis", "Bitches Brew", "85", "NM", "30", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Miles Davis", "Kind of Blue", "84", "VG+", "15", ""), 
                    Array("Miles Davis", "Kind of Blue", "83", "VG", "10", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Miles Davis", "Miles Ahead", "87", "NM", "15", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Miles Davis", "Round About Midnight", "86", "NM", "45", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Miles Davis", "Star People", "88", "M", "15", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Motley Crue", "Theatre of Pain", "4", "VG", "5", ""), 
                    Array("Motley Crue", "Theatre of Pain", "16", "VG", "5", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Muddy Waters", "At Newport", "89", "VG+", "10", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Muddy Waters", "Hard Again", "90", "VG++", "15", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Otis Redding", "In Person at the Whisky a Go Go", "28", "VG++", "20", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Otis Redding", "Otis Blue", "92", "VG+", "12", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Otis Redding", "The Dock of the Bay", "91", "VG++", "20", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Ozzy Osbourne", "Bark at the Moon", "95", "VG++", "15", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Ozzy Osbourne", "Blizzard of Ozz", "93", "VG++", "10", ""), 
                    Array("Ozzy Osbourne", "Blizzard of Ozz", "94", "VG++", "12", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Parliament", "Mothership Connection", "96", "VG", "8", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Parliament", "Motor Booty Affair", "97", "NM", "12", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Pink Floyd", "Wish You Were Here", "15", "NM", "17", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Sly & the Family Stone", "Stand!", "100", "NM", "20", ""), 
                    Array("Sly & the Family Stone", "Stand!", "98", "VG", "8", ""), 
                    Array("Sly & the Family Stone", "Stand!", "99", "VG++", "15", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Taj Mahal", "Giant Step", "6", "VG+", "13", ""), 
                    Array("Taj Mahal", "Giant Step", "19", "VG+", "10", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Talking Heads", "Remain in Light", "101", "VG++", "15", ""), 
                    Array("Talking Heads", "Remain in Light", "102", "VG+", "10", ""), 
                    Array("Talking Heads", "Remain in Light", "103", "NM", "20", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Talking Heads", "Talking Heads 77", "104", "NM", "25", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("The Allman Brothers Band", "At Fillmore East", "105", "VG++", "15", ""), 
                    Array("The Allman Brothers Band", "At Fillmore East", "106", "VG++", "15", ""), 
                    Array("The Allman Brothers Band", "At Fillmore East", "11", "NM", "16", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("The Allman Brothers Band", "Eat a Peach", "8", "G", "3", ""), 
                    Array("The Allman Brothers Band", "Eat a Peach", "9", "VG", "8", ""), 
                    Array("The Allman Brothers Band", "Eat a Peach", "10", "M", "20", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("The Beatles", "Rubber Soul", "24", "M", "1.93", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("The Beatles", "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band", "5", "VG+", "15", ""), 
                    Array("The Beatles", "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band", "27", "VG++", "20", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("The Mothers of Invention", "Freak Out!", "17", "NM", "20", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("The Rolling Stones", "Exile on Main Street", "107", "NM", "25", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("The Rolling Stones", "Let It Bleed", "7", "M", "12", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Thelonious Monk", "Brilliant Corners", "108", "VG++", "30", ""), 
                    Array("Thelonious Monk", "Brilliant Corners", "109", "M", "60", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Thelonious Monk", "Monk's Dream", "110", "VG++", "19", ""), 
                    Array("Thelonious Monk", "Monk's Dream", "26", "NM", "35", "")
                )
            ), 
            Array(
                Array(
                    Array("Willie Nelson", "Phases and Stages", "113", "VG++", "12", "")
                ), 
                Array(
                    Array("Willie Nelson", "Red Headed Stranger", "112", "VG++", "11", ""), 
                    Array("Willie Nelson", "Red Headed Stranger", "111", "VG++", "10", "")
                )
            )
        );











var albumNames = Array(Array("Highway to Hell", "Back in Black"), Array("Call Me", "Let's Stay Together"), Array("Singin' the Blues", "Confessin' the Blues", "Sings Spirituals", "Lucille", "Live at the Regal"), Array("Bad Company"), Array("The Freewheelin' Bob Dylan", "The Times They Are A-Changin'", "Another Side of Bob Dylan", "Bringing It All Back Home", "Highway 61 Revisited", "Blonde on Blonde", "John Wesley Harding", "Nashville Skyline", "Self Portrait", "New Morning", "Blood on the Tracks"), Array("Boston"), Array("Jazz at Massey Hall"), Array("Green River", "Cosmos Factory", "Willy and the Poor Boys"), Array("Time Out", "The Dave Brubeck Quartet at Carnegie Hall"), Array("Longhaired Redneck", "Rides Again"), Array("Ziggy Stardust and the Spiders From Mars", "Hunky Dory"), Array("That's the Way of the World", "Earth, Wind & Fire"), Array("Energized"), Array("All Things Must Pass"), Array("Appetite for Destruction"), Array("Hank Williams Sings"), Array("Empyrean Isles", "Maiden Voyahe", "Head Hunters", "Sextant", "Crossings"), Array("Sports", "Picture This"), Array("Its a Beautiful Day"), Array("Prisoner of Love"), Array("Are You Experienced"), Array("Travelin'", "John Lee Hooker Plays and Sings the Blues"), Array("Fat Man Suicide"), Array("Round About Midnight", "Miles Ahead", "Kind of Blue", "Bitches Brew", "Star People"), Array("Theatre of Pain"), Array("At Newport", "Folk Singer", "Brass and the Blues", "Hard Again"), Array("The Dock of the Bay", "Otis Blue", "In Person at the Whisky a Go Go"), Array("Blizzard of Ozz", "Bark at the Moon"), Array("Mothership Connection", "Motor Booty Affair"), Array("Wish You Were Here"), Array("Look What the Cat Dragged In"), Array("The Genius of Ray Charles", "Modern Sounds in Country and Western Music", "The Genius Sings the Blues"), Array("Stand!", "Fresh"), Array("Giant Step", "Taj Mahal", "Happy Just to Be Like I Am", "Music Keeps Me Together"), Array("Remain in Light", "Talking Heads 77", "Speaking in Tongues"), Array("Eat a Peach", "At Fillmore East"), Array("Please Please Me", "A Hard Day's Night", "Help!", "Rubber Soul", "Revolver", "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band", "Magical Mystery Tour", "The Beatles (White Album)", "Abbey Road", "Let It Be"), Array("Freak Out!"), Array("Exile on Main Street", "Big Hits (High Tide and Green Grass)", "Let It Bleed"), Array("Brilliant Corners", "Evidence", "Monk's Dream"), Array("Red Headed Stranger", "Yesterday's Wine", "Phases and Stages", "The Sound in Your Mind"));

function byId(id){
      return document.getElementById ?  document.getElementById(id) : document.all[id];
    }
    function populateAlbums(index) {
      var i = byId('albumSelect').options.length;
      for (; i>=0; i--) {
          byId('albumSelect').remove(i);
      }

      var artistAlbums = albumNames[index];
      for (i = 0; i < artistAlbums.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = artistAlbums[i];
        option.value = artistAlbums[i];
        try      { byId('albumSelect').add(option, null); } // non-IE
        catch(e) { byId('albumSelect').add(option); } // IE
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: loose the Array and just use square brackets  `var arr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];`

Comment: I don't know your scenario but if you're going to send this at each page request you're probably wasting alot of bandwidth.

Comment: You might want to consider using JavaScript array constant notation: `["a", "b", "c"]` instead of the "Array()" constructor.

Comment: There's an additional reason to head the other peoples suggestion to replace `Array()` with `[]`: Security.  There isn't any guarantee that the Array constructor hasn't been overwritten by someone evil.  The array literal syntax prevents you from leaking information in such a case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your strings contains double-quotes:

```
Array("Mazaak", "Fat Man Suicide", "25", "M", "200", "Includes classics like "Cream Green and Beans" and the title track "Fat Man Suicide"!")
```

You can escape them with black-slashes

```
Array("Mazaak", "Fat Man Suicide", "25", "M", "200", "Includes classics like \"Cream Green and Beans\" and the title track \"Fat Man Suicide\"!")
```

or use single-quotes around the string

```
Array("Mazaak", "Fat Man Suicide", "25", "M", "200", 'Includes classics like "Cream Green and Beans" and the title track "Fat Man Suicide"!')
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array("Mazaak", "Fat Man Suicide", "25", "M", "200", "Includes classics like "Cream Green and Beans" and the title track "Fat Man Suicide"!")`

Your not escaping your literal `"` in your strings so the code is breaking. Go into the php and do some replace on `"` with `\"`

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping the string that you're printing in your JS code.

When there's a syntax error in JS, the rest of the script is not even evaluated, so you'll never find anything below the syntax error.

Three suggestions:

- Use [`addslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) before printing the string.
- Use the compact syntax for array creation:

Example:

```
var inventoryNames =
    [
        [
            [
                ["AC/DC", "Back in Black", "36", "VG++", "12", ""], 
                ["AC/DC", "Back in Black", "37", "VG", "8", ""]
            ), 
            [
                ["AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "30", "VG++", "10", ""], 
                ["AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "38", "VG", "5", ""], 
                ["AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "35", "NM", "16", ""], 
                ["AC/DC", "Highway to Hell", "39", "NM", "14", ""]
            ]
        ],
```

- Post your JS/HTML related questions using something like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Good luck!